# How to encapsulate data of a type to be specific to the parent type in graphql

Tags: graphql, prisma, prisma-graphql

I have this game type:

```
type Game {
  id: ID! @id
  goals: [Goal]
}
```

which have a Goal relationship to:

```
type Goal {
  id: Int! @id(strategy: SEQUENCE) @sequence(name: "IncID", initialValue: 1, allocationSize: 20)
  thumbnail: String!
  player: String!
  minute: Int!
}
```

what i'm trying to do by that "id" mess is to create an incremental id value for the goal, for the purpose of creating a url for each goal, like this:

domaine.com/game/{id-of-the-game}/goal/{incremental-id(1,2..)}

the problem is, the Goal type looks like it is an entity of its own, it is gonna keep the last incremented id even if it is new game.

so i want to reset the id sequence for each new game.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you ask for is not possible using the @id annotation. Each type in the prisma model needs to have a unique id to identify the object in the database. If the underlying database used is MongoDB there will be a Goal collection with documents in it, each representing an individual Goal identified by the id. If the underlying database used is MySQL/PostgreSQL the Goals will be stored in a Goal table with each row representing an individual Goal.

Each individual object (no matter if it is stored as a document or row) needs to be uniquely identified to access it and to create relations, e.g. between Goal objects and Game objects.

If the Goal id would start at 1 for each Game this would violate the unique constraint for the id field since two Goals in the table or collection would be identified by the same id (e.g. 1).

What I would suggest is to simply add something like a "numberInGame" field to the Goal type and fill it while creating the Goal (e.g. by taking goals.length in the Game.type into consideration).

Hope that helped to clarify the id field uniqueness constraint.

Comment: I'm using postgres, and by doing what i'm trying to do above, there would be multiple goals with the same id constaint, which is not possible by definition.
all i have to do is to create another field to hold the incremental value of the goals.
that was silly of me.
thanks perdox.